# Emailing a picture to a Google App Engine site

Tags: google-app-engine, email, quota

I would like to create an app such that I can send an email with a JPEG attachment and then display it on my site.  I am fairly certain that the [Mail API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/) allows me to do this, but if it isn't possible please let me know.

My biggest concern is what are the limits on the attachment size my app can receive, and what are the quotas related to receiving email?  The [email quotas](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits) I saw seemed to specify quotas for outgoing email.  Is it different for incoming mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incoming emails are [directed to one of your application's request handlers](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail.html) for processing, so they are very likely to be subject to [the same limitations](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Quotas_and_Limits) as any other incoming request. 10 Mb is the size limit for a handled request.